# Are $X$ and $Y$ independent or uncorrelated?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

let $Z$ be a uniformly distributed random variable over the range $[-1,1]$

let $X=Z$ and $Y=Z^2$ be random variables.

a) Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

b) Are $X$ and $Y$ uncorrelated?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Please, edit your question with some information about what you've tried and where you're getting stuck.  You'll find that you'll get much more help if you do!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $X$ and $Y$ are **not independent**.  For informally, if we know that $|X|$ is small, then we know that $X^2$ is small. We now give a more formal version of this observation.

Let $A$ be the event $--1/2\le X\le 1/2$. Then $\Pr(A)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Let $B$ be the event $0\le Y\le \frac{1}{4}$. Then $\Pr(B)=\frac{1}{2}$.

The event $A\cap B$ happens precisely if $A$ happens. So $\Pr(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Finally, note that $\Pr(A)\Pr(B)=\frac{1}{4}\ne \Pr(A\cap B)$.

Thus $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

---

But the two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are **uncorrelated.** To show this, we show that $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$.

By symmetry, $E(X)=0$, so $E(X)E(Y)=0$.

We now calculate $E(XY)$. This is $E(Z^3)$. By symmetry it is clear that $E(Z^3)=0$. But if this is not obvious, note that
$$E(Z^3)=\int_{-1}^1 z^3\cdot\frac{1}{2}\,dz=0.$$
Since $E(XY)=0$, we have $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$.